# Проблема с lib-names-soft.h при кросскомпиляции QT под armbian

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, кросс-компиляция

Компилирую `QT5.12.3` под устройство `armbian`. Для конфигурации (`./configure`) использую следующие опции:

```
./configure -prefix /home/asianirish/Install/qt5/qtbase -opensource -confirm-license \
    -debug \
    -prefix /home/asianirish/Qt-custom/qt-embedded-5.12.3 \
    -sysroot /home/asianirish/img/armbian \
    -c++std c++11 \
    -device linux-arm-generic-g++ \
    -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- \
    -openssl \
    -no-widgets \
    -no-gif -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg \
    -no-opengl \
    -skip qtwebengine \
    -nomake examples \
    -v
```

Конфигурация заканчивается успехом:

```
/*
Note: Also available for Linux: linux-clang linux-icc

Note: No wayland-egl support detected. Cross-toolkit compatibility disabled.

WARNING: QDoc will not be compiled, probably because libclang could not be located. This means that you cannot build the Qt documentation.

Either ensure that llvm-config is in your PATH environment variable, or set LLVM_INSTALL_DIR to the location of your llvm installation.
On Linux systems, you may be able to install libclang by installing the libclang-dev or libclang-devel package, depending on your distribution.
On macOS, you can use Homebrew's llvm package.
On Windows, you must set LLVM_INSTALL_DIR to the installation path.

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into '/home/asianirish/img/armbian/home/asianirish/Qt-custom/qt-embedded-5.12.3'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.
*/
```

Но, после выполнения `make` выдает ошибку:

```
...
In file included from kernel/qdnslookup_unix.cpp:59:0:
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/gnu/lib-names.h:8:33: fatal error: gnu/lib-names-soft.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:20940: recipe for target '.obj/qdnslookup_unix.o' failed
make[3]: *** [.obj/qdnslookup_unix.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/asianirish/Install/qt5/qtbase/src/network'
Makefile:273: recipe for target 'sub-network-make_first' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-network-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/asianirish/Install/qt5/qtbase/src'
Makefile:50: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/asianirish/Install/qt5/qtbase'
Makefile:89: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

Захожу в `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/gnu/` и точно, там лежит только `lib-names-hard.h`, никакого `lib-names-soft.h` там нет!

```
>pwd
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/gnu
>ls
libc-version.h  lib-names-hard.h  stubs-hard.h
lib-names.h     stubs.h           stubs-soft.h
```

И что это за `lib-names-soft.h` такой? Лезу в `lib-names.h` и вижу:

```
#if !defined __ARM_PCS_VFP
# include <gnu/lib-names-soft.h>
#endif
#if defined __ARM_PCS_VFP
# include <gnu/lib-names-hard.h>
#endif
```

Гуглю `__ARM_PCS_VFP` и выясняю, что это способ использования чисел с плавающей точкой - хардверовый или софтверовый. Ну окей, решаюсь на грязный хак - добавляю в файл `linux_device_post.conf` (из опенсорсного пакета QT) строку:

```
#Внимание, грязный хак, не повторяйте!
QMAKE_CFLAGS        += -mfloat-abi=hard
```

Но, как и ожидалось - фэйл:

```
/*
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:1230: recipe for target '../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5.12.3' failed
make[3]: *** [../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5.12.3] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/asianirish/Install/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib'
Makefile:223: recipe for target 'sub-corelib-make_first' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-corelib-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/asianirish/Install/qt5/qtbase/src'
Makefile:50: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/asianirish/Install/qt5/qtbase'
Makefile:89: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
*/
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Где взять этот  `lib-names-soft.h`? Я думаю, подсунуть его будет еще более грязным хаком, так что не буду и пытаться. Может в конфигурации изменить `-device-option`? Или `-device`? На что? Куда копать?

Comment: последний лог явно не полный

Comment: @user7860670 ну да, еще впереди несколько экранов ;)

Comment: Ну вот их стоило бы привести, а то что в конце - как раз не особо важнл

Comment: @user7860670 Ладно, намек понял, посмотрю внимательно что там

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Где взять этот lib-names-soft.h?

Для arm'а выбор, используется ли ABI с железной математикой или с софтверной определяется на этапе сборки тулчейна (gcc+binutils+libc). Собственно `hf` в кортеже компилятора `arm-linux-gnueabihf` говорит о том, что этот тулчейн был собран, чтобы производить на выходе бинарники с одноимённым ABI.

Если целевая система представляет собой softfloat систему, то нужно найти/собрать другой тулчейн; `lib-names-soft.h` будет там из коробки.

> Может в конфигурации изменить `-device-option`?

Да, это будет верным решением:

```
-device-option DISTRO_OPTS=hard-float
```

> добавляю в файл linux_device_post.conf (из опенсорсного пакета QT) строку

В принципе этого должно было бы хватить... Возможно, просто забыл очистить каталог сборки перед пересборкой? Или забыл изменить `CXXFLAGS`?

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую. Каталог сборки чищу с помощью `git submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -dfx"`.

Comment: Кстати странно, что он вообще сконфигурировался без ошибок...